# Python Docker on raspberry 64 can't install TensorFlow

Tags: docker, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, arm64

OS:

```
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v8+ #1421 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 27 14:01:37 BST 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Docker image:

```
FROM python as base

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Got:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
```

It works fine on other systems, except raspbian 64 for me.

What could be the reason?

Comment: There can be various reasons for this error. The most common being the version of python3. Which version of Python and TF are you trying?

Comment: I am trying the latest python from the official docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/python. Also tried 3.7 pythons from 3.7-buster, the result is the same

Comment: the same docker file builds and run on MAC, but stops on Raspberry

Comment: That is strange! If possible, give a try to the official docker image of Tensorflow instead of building a custom one using Dockerfile. Try `docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow` or `docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`.